# App crashes when using react native picker Component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jsx, picker

Hello all for listing some items within drop down menu I'm using react native picker component , but the thing is when I changed the `label` and `value` component the app crashes.Following is my customized code.Please check and help me.

**updated code**

```
     render(){
   const data_id =  this.state.workers.map(a => a.worker_id);
   console.log(data_id);
    return(

        <View style={{flex:1}}>

           <Card>
             <CardSection>
               <Text style={{fontSize:16,padding:3}}>{this.props.Work_Category}</Text>
               <View>

               <Dropdown
                 label="select worker"
                 data={data_id}
                  />
               </View>
             </CardSection>
           </Card>
        </View>
    );
  }
}
```

When ever I changed the `value` and `label` component of `Picker` like the way above , the app crashes.Otherwise there will be no problem if the `value` and `label` components are strings.I don't whats wrong.Please..help..

Comment: What error are you getting after app is being crashed ?

Comment: App exit after crashing.I don't know what's the mistake.I've used `react-native-material-dropdown` , after that I'm able to run the app. But the problem is how do I map over responseData within `Dropdown` component. `<Dropdown
                 label="select worker"
                 data={this.state.workers.map(a => a.worker_id)}
                  />` I've done like this but after clicking on drop down no value is displaying.Is there any problem in mapping within drop down? https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PfTb.png please check this image

Comment: Have you tried to debug the application flow where it is going to crash ?

Comment: Yes, after changing the string values from Picker component with maped data from server.So I've changed `Picker`.Now the problem is I'm not getting values after selecting drop down. Could you please check my updated code?

Comment: please specify the workers JSON sample data in the question

Comment: I avoid using `Picker` and used`react-native-material-dropdown`.There is a custom property function for fetching json object.Now its working fine.